# What happened to General Grievous's body in Revenge of the Sith?

Tags: star-wars, droids

What happened to General Grievous's body after he died in *Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith*?

Could his body have been re-used or was it destroyed with the rest? I heard that it was used to make a another droid.

Answer (score 9):

As per [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Grievous):

> Following the Declaration of a New Order, clone troopers recovered Grievous's body, transporting it and his captured starfighter to one of Emperor Palpatine's secret storehouses on Utapau. There it would remain to collect dust for years, until the cyberneticist Nycolai Kinesworthy used the body of the general for the N-K Project, to create the highly advanced droid [N-K Necrosis](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/N-K_Necrosis).
>
> This war droid enjoyed a brief life in the Myyydril Caverns on Kashyyyk, before being destroyed by an anonymous group of spacers. The combatants looted the droid's remains, taking its weaponry and anything else they deemed valuable (*source: "Star Wars Galaxies" MMORPG game*)

Comment: That game isn't canon though, is it?